# Crash with AsyncLayoutInflater when trying to populate the view with data

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, layout-inflater

I have a custom ViewGroup and I am trying to inflate it async, it crashes with the following: 
Process: com.xxx.xxx.debug, PID: 9391
                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
                                                                                       Process: com.xxx.xxx.debug, PID: 9391
                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

AsyncLayoutInflater asyncLayoutInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(this.getContext());
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, myLayout,
                                new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onInflateFinished(View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i++) {
                                            TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                                            tagTextView.setText(myData.get(i).getName());
                                            ImageView myIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
                                            picasso.load(myData.get(i).getIcon()).into(myIcon);
                                            parent.addView(view);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `parent.addView(view)` inside your loop. After that `View` has been added the first time through, you can't add it again, thus the Exception.

Each `inflate()` call inflates only one `View`, which can be added to its parent only once. If you want to inflate multiple `my_row` instances, you'll have to call `inflate()` once for each.

A possible solution is to move the loop to around the `inflate()` call, and keep an `int` field to track which row is being delivered to the `onInflateFinished()` method. Since inflate requests are queued in the `AsyncLayoutInflater`, they will finish in order.

For example, first declare the row counter and `OnInflateFinishedListener`.

```
private int row;

private final AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener inflateListener =
    new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflateFinished(View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            myTextView.setText(myData.get(row).getName());
            ImageView myIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
            picasso.load(myData.get(i).getIcon()).into(myIcon);

            parent.addView(view);
            row++;
        }
    };
```

Then modify the loop and `inflate()` block as follows.

```
row = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i++) {
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, myLayout, inflateListener);
}
```

If you don't need the data collection after the inflation, you could instead remove each element from the start of the collection as it's used, and forgo the row counter, which might be a little cleaner.

Comment: That only add one view to the parent where the actual goal here is to add views (children) to the parent (layout)

Comment: Only one `View` will be inflated for each `inflate()` call, and that one `View` is what's passed into `onInflateFinished()`. A `View` can only be added to its parent once. I didn't realize it before, but your loop would just set the text and image on the same `View`s over and over again. If you want multiple `my_row` layouts inflated, your logic is a little off. You would need to call `inflate()` for each row you need to create.

Comment: I put together a possible solution, and edited it into the answer. I don't have a chance to test it right now, but it should be good. I'll review and test it when I get a chance a little later.

Comment: Oh, you saw it. :-) Lemme know if you have any problems with it. Cheers!

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I think I might tweak it for my purpose but you have give me the right idea and the right path to follow. Cheers